# react native conditional styling (More than two states)?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styles, jsx

I am trying to achieve conditional styling in react native for a component:

the aim is to have three background colors:locked, unlocked, just unlocked

I am short on the syntax for this ?

```
<View style={[styles.insideContainer, !locked && styles.insideContainerValid, !Recent && styles.insideContainerRecent]}>
```

I read once about push style to prop, but again i am short on syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const background  = Recent ? insideContainerRecent : locked ? : styles.insideContainerInvalid : styles.insideContainerValid
```

The last style I don't know that you call, but this should work, you can put inside the array if you want, but I think this is easier to read.